# convert date to Mysql date format php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have this date format in my db

```
19th April 2013
```

I want to convert it to

```
2013-04-19
```

I have used if,else conditions , BUt it becomes too long and complicated .Are there any built in functions ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `PHP's` `date` function

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("19th April 2013"));
```

Answer (score 2):

yes below code to change date format

```
date("Y-m-d",strtotime("19th April 2013")); to get as 2013-04-19
```

and for second one

```
    date("Y/m/d",strtotime("17th April 2013")); to get as 2013-04-17
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still do it via query so you will not have any conversion on `PHP` side. Since the data type of the column is string, you need to convert it to a valid date using `STR_TO_DATE`.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(columnname, '%D %M %Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') new_format
FROM   TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7281e/1)

Answer (score 1):

following PHP code convert the date into desired format

```
 $date = '19th April 2013'
 echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

and other formats are as follows

```
April 22, 2013  date("F d, Y",strtotime($myrow['date']));
Monday, April 22, 2013  date("l, F d, Y",strtotime($myrow['date']));
Apr 22, 2013    date("M d, Y",strtotime($myrow['date']));
22 April 2013   date("d F Y",strtotime($myrow['date']));
22 Apr 2013 date("d M Y",strtotime($myrow['date']));
Mon, 22 Apr 2013    date("D, d M Y",strtotime($myrow['date']));
Monday, the 22nd of April, 2013 date("l",strtotime($myrow['date'])) . ", the " .   date("jS",strtotime($myrow['date'])) . " of " . date("F, Y",strtotime($myrow['date']));
```