# simple html dom, scraping error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper\au_div_puller.php on line 60

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written a scraper in php using simple html Dom.

Problem is that it returns the results but gives me an error

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix it please
Error is:

> > Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\scraper\au_div_puller.php on line 60

Many thanks 
Line 60 is

> $Ex_Date = $tr->find('td', 0)->plaintext; // Find the first TD (starts with 0)

```
 <?php
    //REQUIRED FILES
    require ('connect_mysql.php');
    require('simple_html_dom.php');

//SET VARIABLES OF WEBSITE TO CRAWL
$url = ('http://www.shares.com/ANZ');  //WEBSITE TO SCRAPE WITH MYSQL INJECTED FROM ABOVE
echo ($url . "<br>");

//SET USER AGENT TO BE GOOGLEBOT
        $opts = array  ('http'=>array(  'method'=>"GET", 'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)', ));
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        //$html = new simple_html_dom();
        $response = file_get_html($url, false, $context);
        $html = str_get_html($response);

//CHECK IT IS NOT A 404 PAGE IF SO SKIP
if (!empty($html)) {
//CHECK IT IS NOT BLANK PAGE OR EMPTY PAGE IF SO SKIP
$count = count($html->find('table'));
if($count > 0){

//START TABLE PROCESSING
$table = $html->find('table', 0); // ID LOCK IE TABLE 0 (first table) Get the first table ??
foreach($table ->find('tr') as $tr) {     // Foreach row in the table!
$Ex_Date = $tr->find('td', 0)->plaintext; // Find the first TD (starts with 0)
if($Ex_Date == "" || $Ex_Date == "&nbsp;") continue;  // Don't allow empty records
$Amount = $tr->find('td', 1)->plaintext; // Find the second TD (which will be 1)
$Franked = $tr->find('td', 2)->plaintext; // Find the third TD (which will be 2)
$Franking_Credit = $tr->find('td', 3)->plaintext; // Find the fourth TD (which will be 3)
$Books_Close = $tr->find('td', 4)->plaintext; // Find the fifth TD (which will be 4)
$Date_Payable = $tr->find('td', 5)->plaintext; // Find the sixth TD (which will be 5)


//MYSQL DATA FORMATTING
//ESCAPE STRINGS AND DATE FORMATTING
//Now validate the data with mysqli_real_escape_string(). This function will escape characters that cause problems, like single quotes.
//Note there needs to be an open connection to the MySQL server for this work, otherwise you'll have blank strings returned.
// convert 04-Dec-1997 to yyyy-mm-dd formate
// for other versions of date format see:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139696/convert-date-to-mysql-date-format-php
$Ex_Date_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Ex_Date);
    $Ex_Date_c = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Ex_Date_c)); //fix date format
$Amount_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Amount);
$Franked_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Franked);
$Franking_Credit_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Franking_Credit);
$Books_Close_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Books_Close);
    $Books_Close_c = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Books_Close_c));//fix date format
$Date_Payable_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Date_Payable);
    $Date_Payable_c = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date_Payable_c));//fix date format


//MYSQL INSERT TIME AND TESTING
//MYSQL INSERT QUERY
$sql = "INSERT INTO $insertintotable    (stockcode, exchange, exdate, amount, franked, frankingcredit, booksclose, datepayable, updatedatetime)
                            VALUES      ('$stockcode', 'ASX', '$Ex_Date_c', '$Amount_c', '$Franked_c', '$Franking_Credit_c', '$Books_Close_c', '$Date_Payable_c', '$updatedatetime')";
//MYSQL RESULT TEST
//echo ($sql . "<br>");  // Show the Mysql query

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)   {
 //                                 echo "New record created successfully <br>";  //TESTING --- Uncomment this code after verifying that the echo statements produce valid INSERT queries.
                                    }
                                    else {echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;}

}
}
}
}
// CLOSE AND CLEAR SESSION
$html->clear();
unset($html);
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This is a prepared statement I could use that I copied off a learning site

```
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

// set parameters and execute
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

$firstname = "Mary";
$lastname = "Moe";
$email = "mary@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

$firstname = "Julie";
$lastname = "Dooley";
$email = "julie@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Check your $html if it's the right result or not

Comment: sounds like you found a `<TR>` that only has a `<TH>` in it...so your td will fail.

Comment: To expand upon what @Forbs said, the error is saying that something you've written as an object is not really an object.  If, for example, you write something like `$a->plaintext`, you are expecting $a to be an object with a property named `plaintext`.  But what if `$a` is really null?  You'll get the `property of non object` error.  So in your case, while `$tr` is an object, the method `find('td', 0)` didn't find anything and didn't return an object.  Therefore when it tries to execute `find('td', 0)->plaintext`, It complains because it's trying to find a property of a null value.

Comment: RE: Other Question. I didnt mean delete the whole question, just what you put in an Answer that wasn't an Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't guarantee that `find('td', 0)` will find a value, you must guarantee that you don't try to ask for the property `plaintext` if there is no td found.

```
$table = $html->find('table', 0); // ID LOCK IE TABLE 0 (first table) Get the first table ??
foreach($table ->find('tr') as $tr) {     // Foreach row in the table!
    if($td = $tr->find('td', 0)) {
        $Ex_Date = $td->plaintext; // Find the first TD (starts with 0)
        // ... and so on for each variable
```

Granted, it's not as sexy as chaining them together, but the chaining only works if you *know* that the first method (`$td` in my example) will always return an object having the method/property you're calling.

On a side note, you should also look at using prepared statements (`values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`) instead of sticking values into your `$sql` variable.

Comment: I am very grateful for your code.  Thank you for taking the time to look at it and I have updated the code and there is not no error :)))))))   I have looked at prepared statements just now as you mentioned I could do something like the below but dont know where or how to place it in could you make some suggestions when you get a moment please

Comment: SEE ABOVE `code` // prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

// set parameters and execute
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

$firstname = "Mary";
$lastname = "Moe";
$email = "mary@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

$firstname = "Julie";
$lastname = "Dooley";
$email = "julie@example.com";
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();`code`

Comment: The part you're missing is binding the parameters.  TBH, I don't use native php commands; I use my own abstraction class, so I'm not too familiar with how the various mysqli, pdo, etc commands work.  But if you're using PDO, the parameters are sent in an array through the execute method.  See example 2 http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: BTW, If my answer to your question solved your problem, please consider accepting it or voting the answer up.